# Cross Apply in SFMC SQL Query Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio, activities

```
SELECT
  e.cust_id AS customer_id,
  e.event_id AS event_id,
  max(t.updatedON)  as recent_timestamp
FROM
  event_table AS e
  INNER JOIN car AS c ON e.cust_id = c.cust_id and e.event_id = c.event_id
  INNER JOIN walk AS w ON e.cust_id = w.cust_id and e.event_id = w.event_id
  CROSS APPLY (values(c.updated_On),(w.updated_on)) as t(updatedOn)
  group by e.cust_id, e.event_id
```

> Error: An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: The values(values(c.updated_On table has a multi-part specification. This is not allowed. values(values(c.updated_On is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views.

The three data extensions `event_table`, `car` and `walk` do exist. Any ideas what i can do to resolve?

EDIT: Included sample data and desired output [here](https://pastebin.com/GuQBMQEG).

EDIT 2: The accepted answer below is correct and should remain for helping others. Since the implementation however changed `OUTER APPLY` to act as `INNER JOIN`, I did some cleaning:

```
SELECT e.cust_id, e.event_id,
CASE 
  WHEN
    car.updated_on >= motorcycle.updated_on and car.updated_on >= walk.updated_on
      THEN car.updated_on
  WHEN motorcycle.updated_on >= car.updated_on
      THEN motorcycle.updated_on
  ELSE walk.updated_on
END as updated_on
FROM
  event_table AS e
  INNER JOIN car AS car ON e.cust_id = car.cust_id
  INNER JOIN motorcycle AS motorcycle ON e.cust_id = motorcycle.cust_id
  INNER JOIN walk AS walk ON e.cust_id = walk.cust_id
WHERE
  e.event_id = car.event_id
  AND e.event_id = motorcycle.event_id
  AND e.event_id = walk.event_id
```

Comment: Are you getting the error in a Query Activity or in Query Studio?

Comment: Pretty sure `values` is not supported in SFMC.

Comment: Hey Adam, thanks for respond. I am doing this in `Automation Studio > Query Activity`. All i want to do is get the `GREATEST` date of three columns and i can't figure out how :(

Comment: what's the third column -- `car.updatedON`, `walk.updatedOn` and __?

Comment: `motorcycle.updatedOn`, sorry. I simplified it for easier example. Same structure as the other two tables. Just one more complexity to since there's 3 tables to consider instead of two. `Car, Motorcycle and Walk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only see two `updatedON` values.  If you only need to find the greatest of those two then you could do something like this:

```sql
select
  e.cust_id customer_id
, e.event_id event_id
, case 
    when c.updatedon >= w.updatedon 
         and c.updatedon >= m.updatedon then c.updatedon
    when w.updatedon >= m.updatedon then w.updatedon
    else m.updatedon 
  end recent_timestamp
from event_table e
outer apply (
  select 
  max(c0.updatedon) updatedon
  from car c0 
  where e.cust_id = c0.cust_id 
  and e.event_id = c0.event_id
) c
outer apply (
  select 
  max(w0.updatedon) updatedon
  from walk w0 
  where e.cust_id = w0.cust_id 
  and e.event_id = w0.event_id
) w
outer apply (
  select 
  max(m0.updatedon) updatedon
  from motorcycle m0 
  where e.cust_id = m0.cust_id 
  and e.event_id = m0.event_id
) w
where m.updatedOn is not null
and w.updatedOn is not null
and c.updatedOn is not null
```

The OUTER APPLYs are acting like LEFT JOINs but with the criteria inside.

Comment: Well poop, too slow yet again. I was just about to post something similar.

Comment: Is `OUTER APPLY`/`LEFT JOIN` correct in this instance? I only want the result set that exists in all tables. E.g. the `cust_id` and `event_id` needs to exist in 1) `event_table`, 2) `car`, 3) `walk` and if we're talking about the last case then also in `motorcycle` which is same structure as `car` or `walk`.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Adding another apply for `motorcycle`.  The CASE is a little more complex, but doable with 3 values.  The WHERE forces the the LEFT JOIN to only include matches in all three.

Comment: Hey Adam, thanks again. Let me try this one, the previous one did not work as expected for my test data. Will see how this one works, I did add a link to test data I am using if it add clarity. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I can't edit your post. There is an alias typo on the third outer apply. I believe it should be `m` instead of `w. It worked like a charm. Thanks so much. Very good use of `WHERE` to force a `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. That did not occur me. Thanks so much, especially with the limitation around `VALUES`

Comment: Your answer is great, thanks again. I marked it as accepted but i also edited my original post. Since you end up treating it as `INNER JOIN` at the end, I simply replaced the `OUTER APPLY` with `INNER JOIN`. Please keep your answer because it was incredibly valuable. Enjoy your day.